# Omega theme sidebar padding

Tags: theming

I've started using the Omega theme, and wanted to apply a vertical gap in between my blocks in the sidebar on the right called sidebar-second. I went into the themes settings, and added an additioanl css in "Additional region classes" but its applied it the whole of the sidebar, and I still have no gaps. I have tried inspecting in firebug, and if I amend 'region-inner' it works but applies to all regions including main content etc. I just wanted the ones in the Sidebar Second. I'm afraid I dont know enough css to - can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this now by adding:-

`.region-sidebar-second .block-inner {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}`

Sorry, it was a lack of knowledge of css causing the problem.